# Entity Framework Core Include Then Left Join Fluent API

Tags: entity-framework

I have a structure of classes that follow logic similar to this...

DBContext1

```
public class Parent {
     public int Id
     public ICollection<Child> child 
}

public class Child {
    public int Id
    public string Item
    public ICollection<Action> action
}

public class Action {
    public int Id
}
```

This is a one to many to many relationship.  I created these tables using entity framework and everything is working well.

My problem is that I want to do a left join from my class child to an object in a different dbContext.  Most of the examples I have seen all do the left join at the parent class level.

For example in DBContext2 I have a class that contains item information.  I want to perform a left join on the item property from the child class in DBContext1.

DBContext2

```
public class Item {
     public string Item
     public string Description
}
```

This below gets me my Parent and Child objects joined together but how do I expand it to do a left join on the item class object

```
using (var dbcontext1 = new DBContext1())
{
     using (var dbcontext2 = new DBContext2())
     {
                var parent = dbcontext1.Parent
                         .Include(ch => ch.Child) 
                          //maybe do groupjoin here... would join parent.Child.item = dbcontext2.item.item
                         .ToList();
     }
 }
```

I have tried doing a GroupJoin but it does not seem to work.  I want to use the Fluent pattern instead of using the "from p in Parent" syntax.  Is there a way to do this?

Edit 1:

```
using (var dbcontext1 = new DBContext1())
{
     using (var dbcontext2 = new DBContext2())
     {
                var parent = dbcontext1.Parent
                         .Include(ch => ch.Child) 
                         .ToList();


                var item = dbcontext2.Item.ToList()

                var query = from p in parent
                            join i in item on p.Child.Item == i.item //how do I do the join correctly?
                            select {
                               //select whatever here
                            }

     }
 }
```

Comments say to do this in two SQL statements.  Running with this approach but struggling how to do the join from the Parent.Child.Item to Item.Item

Comment: I wouldn't try to do this in one query. EF won't be able to generate one SQL statement from the LINQ query anyway and it will switch to client-side evaluation to join results from two different contexts. I'd like to make this evident from the code. Also, what do you mean by *it does not seem to work*?

Comment: @GertArnold Awesome, thank you for the comment and I appreciate the advice.  So in my edit I made a few changes.  Is this kind of what you were thinking if I can get the join working?

Comment: @GertArnold Or would it be even better to just do three queries and then join them together manually?

Comment: The join `p.Child.Item == i.item` looks OK to me if property `Item` uniquely identifies an `Item` entity.